# Popup page remains activated even if the page is gone

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-action

if you click on the browser button, appears a page as a popup page. 
with my program you can turn on music, from the body of the page.
when the window appears, music can be turned on, but when the window goes away, music is stopped. 
does anyone have an idea how it stays turned, without popup appeared to stay?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Are you trying to make music play when the popup is closed, or are you asking how is it alread ydone somewhere? Because your question title sounds like it's already working like that.

Comment: I have a link from another site that turns on the music, and i can turn on the music in popup. but when the popup window goes away, music ist stopped.
my question: 
what should I do, so that music stays turned on without pupup window appeared to stay ?

Comment: Short answer would be - play the music from a background page, as a popup is completely destroyed when closed. See [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed when the popup goes away everything gets torn down.

Depending on how you play the music it might not be available in the background page either. Good luck.